# convert df.apply to spark to run parallely iusing all the cores

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, parallel-processing

We have a [panda dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) that are using.  We have a function we use in retail data which runs on a daily basis row by row to calculate the item to item difference like below

```
for itemiter in range(len(RetDf)):
    column = RetDf.loc[itemiter , "username"]
    RetDf[column] = RetDf.apply(lambda row: ItemDiff(RetDf.loc[itemiter, 'Val'], row['Val']), axis=1)
```

is there a way to convert it to sparkcontext rdd parallelize to use all cores

```
Sample Data with dummy values for retdf: 

username    UserId     Val
abc75757    1234       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0] 
abcraju     4567       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
xyzuser     4343       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
user4abc    2323       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]


FinalOutput: 

username    UserId     Val                     abc75757  abcraju        xyzuser     user4abc
abc75757    1234       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]   2.0       0.0            0.0         1.0
abcraju     4567       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]   2.0       0.0            0.0         1.0
xyzuser     4343       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]   2.0       0.0            0.0         1.0
user4abc    2323       [0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]   2.0       0.0            4.0         1.0

ItemDiff

def ItemDiff(z1,z2):
    distance_t = 0.0
    path_t = [(0,0)]
    distance_t, path_t = fastdtw(z1,z2)
    return(distance_t)
```

Comment: Could you post the input/output you are looking for?

Comment: @MattAndruff .. Thanks for the reply , i have added sample input / output

Comment: @MattAndruff.. Hi Andruff, Any suggestion pls

Comment: I have proposed a solution I think will do what you have hinted at with your code snippet.  I don't know what your function does or how well you know spark, so please if you have questions about my solution please ask and I'll do my best to help explain.

Comment: Are you simply trying to take the array and convert it to colus in some way?  What does your function actually do?

Comment: @MattAndruff . Function will do a subtraction and calculate the minus and create a column and assign the final value to it.  Each and every row will be compared with all other rows. I tried below code but facing issue with last 2 lines. Can you pls help

Comment: @BeRT2me I just added the defination as well

Comment: fastdtw is a library calculates the distance

Comment: @BeRT2me   https://pypi.org/project/fastdtw/

Comment: @BeRT2me can you pls help if there is a way to parallize using spark context rdd or list  or dictionary

Comment: Is there any way you can give an example with some output? Running your current sample data through your calculation gives all `0`'s instead of what you have there.

Comment: @BeRT2me Its okay . 0 is fine. Can you help me with the defination code change

Comment: @BeRT2me Its just a sample data randomly i gave

Comment: @BeRT2me Any help pls

Answer (score 1):

There is [Pandas on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html) which should look into but here it won't help as they don't have a direct translation for `pd.loc`

It seems your doing a cartesian join which is expensive but this is what I suggest you do:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from fastdtw import fastdtw

#Create PySpark SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com") \
    .getOrCreate()
#Create PySpark DataFrame from Pandas
raw_data = { 'username' :[ 'abc75757', 'abcraju', 'xyzuser', 'user4abc'], 'UserId':[ 1234, 4567,4343,2323], 'Val': [[0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0] ,[0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],[0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],[0.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]]}
RetDf = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

def ItemDiff(z1,z2):
 distance_t = 0.0
 path_t = [(0,0)]
 distance_t, path_t = fastdtw(z1,z2)
 return float(distance_t)

itemDiff = udf(ItemDiff, FloatType()) # create UDF to do work.


sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(RetDf) 
cartesianJoin = sparkDF.crossJoin(sparkDF)\ # this is expensive but necessary
.toDF("UserId","Val","username","myUserId","myVal","my_username")\ #renaming the columns for convience
.select( itemDiff( "Val", "myVal" ).alias("dist"), f.col("*") )\ # run UDF 
.groupBy( "Val","UserId","username" )\ # this enables us to pivot 
.pivot("my_username")\ #exposes the calculation  be careful to uses the 'exploded' column.  
.max("dist").show() #handy tick as their is only 1 value so max is just the number.
+--------------------+------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+        
|                 Val|UserId|username|abc75757|abcraju|user4abc|xyzuser|
+--------------------+------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]|  1234|abc75757|     0.0|    0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
|[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]|  4343| xyzuser|     0.0|    0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
|[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]|  4567| abcraju|     0.0|    0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
|[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]|  2323|user4abc|     0.0|    0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
+--------------------+------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

[UDF documentation  here.](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html)
If you can rework your logic to avoid using a UDF, it would run faster, but you'd need to learn what spark sql functions you could use to do the same things.  This might be a good time to review if you really need all the data to calculate the columns or if you can simplify your logic.

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your use case

Comment: Thanks Matt.. i will try this solution and is there a way using Spark Context parallize rdd map to implement this ?

Comment: @Getting Illegal argument

Comment: I'm sorry but the code does run as is... not sure what your error is about?

Comment: I can't see why using RDD's would be faster in this context.

Comment: Thanks Matt. But still getting Number of columns doesnt match error. In the cross join when i tried to run the same command given by you , it says "number of columns doesnt match"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244845/discussion-between-arya-and-matt-andruff).

Answer (score 1):

You've turned a combinations problem in to a product problem, more than doubling the necessary calculations, I'm not sure of a good pure pandas way of doing this... but this should still be much faster even without parallelization.

```
a = [["abc75757", 1234, [4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0]],
     ["abcraju", 4567, [0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0]],
     ["xyzuser", 4343, [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]],
     ["user4abc", 2323, [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0]]]
RetDf = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['username', 'UserId', 'Val'])
```

```
from itertools import combinations

combos = combinations(RetDf[['username', 'Val']].to_numpy(), r=2)
combos = [(x[0][0], x[1][0], fastdtw(x[0][1], x[1][1])[0]) for x in combos]
permuts = [(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in combos] + [(x[1], x[0], x[2]) for x in combos]

df = pd.DataFrame(permuts, columns=['username', 'pair', 'value']).pivot(index='username', columns='pair').droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
output = RetDf.merge(df).fillna(0)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
    username  UserId                   Val  abc75757  abcraju  user4abc  xyzuser                                                                 
0   abc75757    1234  [4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0]       0.0      8.0       5.0      6.0
1   abcraju     4567  [0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0]       8.0      0.0       2.0      3.0
2   xyzuser     4343  [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]       6.0      3.0       1.0      0.0
3   user4abc    2323  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0]       5.0      2.0       0.0      1.0
```

Comment: i just added the function

Comment: Thank You .. I will test it now. Can we do in Spark context the same using RDD ?

Comment: idk Spark... my hope is that someone else can pick up where I've left off.

Comment: I tried this approach but its running too long